SQL server suddenly backups are slow
I've an older SQL 2008R2 server that will dismissed and upgraded this year.
Unfortunately server needs to remain up and running until then.
Problem is since a few days ago, backups are really slow (about 3x slower).
I could notice that it is the identical problem of this problem:
SQL server suddenly backups are slow and async_io_completion shows suspended for long time
When I make a new DB, restore DB from a bak file then backup this DB... The backup time become again ok.
I noticed that the poster of the link solved the problem by Cleared "full backup" execution plans from cache. How can I perform this?
Any help would be great!

Does this help?
